# textbox user interface effect in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can i manage the text box got-focus like user enter on text box then text box back color changed
for example yellow and user move next text box then color will white in whole window form application in c# each and every form text box will do this. how can i do with out using enter and leave event's of c#

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is something like this:

```
textboxName.GotFocus += (s, ea) =>
{
    ((TextBox)s).BackColor = Color.Black;
    ((TextBox)s).ForeColor = Color.White;
};
textboxName.LostFocus += (s, ea) =>
{
    ((TextBox)s).BackColor = Color.White;
    ((TextBox)s).ForeColor = Color.Black;
};
```

Where textboxName is the name of your textbox.

Comment: Personally I have bad experiences with this kind of direct state modification in events. I prefer just triggering a update function which calculates the properties I want to set depending on the state of the form.

Comment: What kinds or bad experiences are you referring to ?

Comment: Exploding complexity because it's hard to predict how many of such events interact. Imagine you want to change the background color to blue if the mouse hovers over your textbox. Then you have two pairs of handlers interacting with the same properties.

Comment: True but I cant seem to find a reason on why you want to have a gotfocus and mouse over event on the same text box changing the same property :P 
So yes.. it is likely to "blow up" when adding more and more events to the textbox. But this is the simplest way to get what the TS wants :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define class that derivative from the GUI object - and override the get focuse.